# How can I set a connection property?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I can connect fine to an Oracle 11.2 database using JDBC driver and the following Java code:

```
  import java.sql.*;
  import javax.sql.DataSource;
  import javax.naming.Context;
  import javax.naming.InitialContext;
  import javax.naming.NamingException;
  import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
  ...
  Connection conn=null;

  // connect to database
  Context context = new InitialContext();
  DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/myPool");
  conn = ds.getConnection();
```

But now I need to set the option `SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary` to true. See page 4-16 here

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/java.112/e10589.pdf

So I try to follow examples from here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/urls.htm

and I modify the code as:

```
  import java.sql.*;
  import java.util.Properties;
  import javax.sql.DataSource;
  import javax.naming.Context;
  import javax.naming.InitialContext;
  import javax.naming.NamingException;
  import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
  ...
  Connection conn=null;

  // set connection properties
  Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
  info.put ("SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary","true");

  // connect to database
  Context context = new InitialContext();
  DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/myPool");
  conn = ds.getConnection(info);
```

and I'm getting the following compile error:

```
myClass.java:1145: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getConnection(java.util.Properties)
location: interface javax.sql.DataSource
          conn = ds.getConnection(info);
                   ^
```

Anyone know how I can properly set `SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary` here?

UPDATE 1

Changing to:

```
  import java.sql.*;
  import java.util.Properties;
  import javax.sql.DataSource;
  import javax.naming.Context;
  import javax.naming.InitialContext;
  import javax.naming.NamingException;
  import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
  import oracle.jdbc.*;       // NEW
  import oracle.jdbc.pool.*;  // NEW
  ...
  Connection conn=null;

  // set connection properties
  Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
  info.put ("SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary","true");

  // connect to database
  Context context = new InitialContext();
  DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/myPool");
  ((OracleDataSource)ds).setConnectionProperties(info); // NEW
  conn = ds.getConnection();                    // NEW
```

gives the following run time error:

`stack trace: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.DataSource40 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource`

Comment: It seems to be an Oracle implementation of `DataSource`. Did you try to cast the `DataSource` retrieved on jndi to `OracleDataSource` ? Ex: `((OracleDataSource)ds).setConnectionProperties(info);` then `conn = ds.getConnection()` should return a connection with your properties correctly set.

Comment: Thanks Alex, well it removed the compile error, but I'm not sure the option was set correctly due to run-time error. See UPDATE 1 above.

Answer (score 3):

The `DataSource` is usually configured on the application server. For example, in `Glassfish` you could set this property in the admin console like this:

[image]

and then just call

`ds.getConnection()` from your client code.

**Edit:**

If you want to get access to the implementation class of `javax.sql.DataSource`, you should use [DataSource#unwrap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Wrapper.html#unwrap(java.lang.Class)) method rather than simple cast.

For example:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/MyPool");
OracleDataSource oracleDS = ds.unwrap(OracleDataSource.class)
```

Make sure, you have your jdbc driver jar on classpath.

But then your code will be non-portable, if you wish to switch to another database vendor in the future.

**Edit 2:**
Also, for `Glassfish`, refer to the [Configuring Specific JDBC Connection Pool Features](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggndx.html#SJSASEEAGgktdi) of Oracle Administration Guide.

Comment: I did what is shown here but it doesn't appear the `true` setting stuck because I'm getting an overflow error whenever I try to setDouble with a number larger than Oracle NUMBER datatype can support (1e127). If the variable is `true` there shouldn't be any conversion to NUMBER.

Comment: @ggkmath these are not complete settings. You should at least provide connection URL, user and password. And the database vendor in your case should be Oracle apparently. Make sure that you're able to successfully ping created connection pool.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm confused. I already had a perfectly working JDBC Connection Pool created in admin console Resources/JDBC/JDBC Connection Pool/myPool, where I've entered all the necessary parameters in the Additional Parameters tab, including user name, pwd, Oracle vendor, etc. So I just added the SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary switch as another property and restarted the domain, and observed the overflow error when writing large numbers to the database (meaning the switch isn't set to true).

Comment: @ggkmath The property should be set the way you described in your second comment to this answer (i.e. in the Additional Parameters of Connection Pool, along with the other connection settings, such as user, password etc.). You must not create an additional pool with just one property. I'm not sure why it didn't work. I'll try this later. As for your update, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks jFrenetic. I also tried adding `-Doracle.jdbc.SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary=true` as an option in the Configurations/server-config/JVM Settings/JVM Options screen. That's where the java heap size is set along with a lot of other things. But this also did not seem to have any effect.

Comment: @ggkmath see another edit as well. Nothing new, just a link to official Administration Guide.

Comment: GlassFish support has informed me "SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary" is not a supported name/value pair. They recommend using setConnectionProperties(java.util.Properties) to set this. There exists an RFE : http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18394 to enable parsing a Properties object passed as a value.

Comment: @ggkmath Hm, this is weird. I just tried that too. I set this property on the connection pool, looked up the `DataSource`, unwrapped the `OracleDataSource`, then called `OracleDataSource#getConnectionProperties` and got `null` :-\ Anyway, it's good that you can at least set this property manually. However, I don't know how it's going to work in the real enterprise project. Perhaps, if you use JPA, you could pass this property in persistence-unit configuration, and `Hibernate` or some other persistence provider, would handle this for you. But I'm not sure :)

Answer (score 2):

This form of `getConnection()` is specific to `OracleDataSource` and doesn't exist in the more generic `DataSource` interface.

The solution is simple, replace this line:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/myPool");
```

with this:

```
OracleDataSource ds = (OracleDataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/myPool");
```

Of course this means that from now on your application will only work with Oracle databases. Depending on what you need this may or may not be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks biziclop, Should the parameter `info`, still be implemented like `conn = ds.getConnection(info);`?

Comment: I'm getting a compile warning: `warning: [deprecation] getConnection(java.util.Properties) in oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource has been deprecated`. Is there another way to set info?

Comment: Ignoring the warning and running the changes also gives the same error as the other two solutions above: `stack trace: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.DataSource40 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource`

Comment: @ggkmath Well, it means then that the documentation you were reading isn't correct for the scenario you're trying to apply it to.

Comment: My GlassFish JDBC Connection Pool has a setting for DataSourceName with a value of OracleDataSource. Also, the Wrap JDBC Object option is enabled. Maybe that's related to the error (?).

Comment: @ggkmath It could be, but why don't you try disabling it?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alex's comment,  I'd try

```
 conn = ds.getConnection();
 conn.setClientInfo("SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary","true");
```